# How to append a label the text from array elements to all the different headers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to add headers which are present inside an array which is obtained from json but the headers only show the last element present not the rest

here is the code

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
    {
        let sectionHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeaderIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderReusableView

```
    for i in 0..<sectionNames.count
    {

        sectionHeaderView.sectionHeader.text = sectionNames[indexPath[i]]
    }

    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

please help thanks in advance!

Comment: post code and show requiremnt as image . If you simply ask a question with no inputs how can you get an answer

Comment: have added the code the issue is also explained plz help

Answer (score 0):

- In your Storyboard, select your collection view, select Accessories –
  Section Header.
- A section header will now appear in your Storyboard. Add a UILabel to
  it.
- Make a new file in your project of type UICollectionReusableView, and
  call it SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView.
- In the Storyboard, select the Section Header Collection Reusable View
  and give it an Identifier, call it “SectionHeader“.
- Then give it a Custom Class: “SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView“
- In the SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView.swift file, make an
  IBOutlet for the label you made and call it headerLabel.
- Finally, in your UICollectionViewController code, add a function:

  ```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView
       {     
         let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView
         header.headerLabel.text = "YOUR_HEADER_TEXT"
         //You can add elements to view instead of just a label
         let view: UIView(frame: CGRect(0,0,200,100))
         view.backgroundColor = .red
         return header}
  ```

Comment: Can you post new issues please? Help us so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop given inside will always iterate till last element, hence always last element will only show, according to the code posted.

So please try removing the for loop, and load only sectionNames at current index.